# Open Source Java/Groovy library for picture file format conversion?

Tags: java, groovy, file-format, image

I need to convert tons of pictures, coming from all kinds of sources, in all kind of file formats. I want to store them all in the PNG file format (even if it means losing e.g. layer data from ESP's).

I'm looking for a library that is preferably open source and has a Java or Groovy API (on top of JNI/JNA, if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick is a very potent image manipulation library and there's a [JNI wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/) available.

Otherwise the [JAI](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html) library supports reading and writing .jpg, .gif, .png, .tiff, .bmp and other files so you might try that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends mainly on the range of formats you need to support.

If you want to stay in Java you can use the `ImageIO` and image related classes of JDK [java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) adding may be the **Java Advanced Imaging** [link text](https://jai.dev.java.net/)

But these will support basic formats like:

- jpg
- bmp
- png
- tiff

Maybe additional image writers are available to be plugged in into this structure..